# Convert Decimal to Time SSRS/SQL

Tags: sql, reporting-services, time

I have a decimal field in a SQL database that stores time only.  Below is the data that is coming across and the end result I would like to display in a SSRS report.  The solution could either be in the SQL query or maybe some type of SSRS formatting/expression.

```
Data      Desired Result
6.50      6:30:00 AM 
14.25     2:25:00 PM
17.75     5:45:00 PM
8.00      8:00:00 AM
```

I greatly appreciate any help with this.

Comment: `select convert(smalldatetime, datediff(day, '1899-12-30T00:00:00', getdate()) + (6.50/24))` will get you to `2017-08-18 06:30:00`

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but if the solution gave the result of: 2017-08-18 06:29:59.970, then could I round that to 2017-08-18 06:30:00 in SSRS?  If so, that would work.

Comment: I just updated the comment. Smalldatetime might work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright this may not be pretty but it gives you the result you are looking for:

```
select convert(time(0), convert(smalldatetime, (6.50/24)))
```

Result:

```
06:30:00
```

Replace the 6.50 with your column name.

Comment: You are my superhero!  Thank you it's perfect!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help